# How to write query for get related videos?

Tags: php, mysql

My tables are :

**tb_videos**

```
id,
name
```

**tb_video_tags**

```
id,
video_id,
tag
```

I want to select videos and their related videos through tags.

Comment: Are you looking for all videos related to just a SINGLE video by some parameter value.  Ex: Video "X" is associated with tags "A", "B", "G", then you want to find all videos associated with "A", "B" and "G"?  Or... do you want just all videos related with tag "A", or... tags "A" OR "B", or... tags "A" AND "G"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
   SELECT v.id, v.name, vr.id AS related_id, vr.name AS related_name
     FROM tb_videos AS v
LEFT JOIN tb_video_tags AS vt
       ON vt.video_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN tb_videos AS vr
       ON vt.video_id = vr.id
      AND v.id != vr.id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT v.name
FROM tb_video_tags t, tb_video v
WHERE v.id = t.video_id
```

try it and have fun